How to make `Cloth` component in Unity behave like ribbon used in Rhythmic Gymnastics?
In Unity, I'm trying to implement the following:

A Rhythmic Gymnastics-ribbon, controlled with the mouse.

Like this:

Problem:
I'm not good at physics and I think implementing this properly requires some knowledge of physics. My current implementation is OK but doesn't feel 100% physically accurate.
In the current setup, I have a Cylinder object that acts as the handle (the handle that the person IRL would hold), and a child Plane object with a Cloth component. The vertices that are near the handle are locked in position.
I move/rotate the handle, and the cloth is supposed to follow like a ribbon. Here's a video showing how it looks:
https://imgur.com/a/XKQIdjd
Here are the settings for the Cloth component:

I'm hoping that the video showcases the inaccuracies it has.

If you compare the video in your post and your recording, the athlet is moving her hand in circles at least 5-10 times faster than you do. They do not give the ribbon as much slack as you are doing.
